# how to covert code from pine script to python

Tags: python, pine-script, pine-script-v4

how to convert this type of code from pine script to python

pine script code

```
get2PoleSSF(src, length) =>
PI = 2 * asin(1)
arg = sqrt(2) * PI / length
a1 = exp(-arg)
b1 = 2 * a1 * cos(arg)
c2 = b1
c3 = -pow(a1, 2)
c1 = 1 - c2 - c3

ssf = 0.0
ssf := c1 * src + c2 * nz(ssf[1]) + c3 * nz(ssf[2])
```

this is the part im trying to convert it to python

[image]

the value of of the code
[image]

I tried this

```py
   def get2PoleSSD(src,length):
        PI = 2* np.arcsin(1)
        arg = np.sqrt(2)* PI / length
        a1 = np.exp(-arg)
        b1 = 2 * a1 *np. cos(arg)
        c2 = b1
        c3 = -pow(a1, 2)
        c1 = 1 - c2 - c3
        df['ssf']  = 0.0
        df['ssf'] = c1* src
        df['ssf_1p'] = df['ssf'].shift(1)
        df['ssf_2p'] = df['ssf'].shift(2)
        df['ssf_n'] = c1 * src + c2 * df['ssf_1p'] + c3 * df['ssf_2p']
```

the value from my code

[image]

but the value doesn't match at all

Comment: You will probably get more help if you can explain what you expect to happen given a certain input and what the expected output might be.  Simply showing a pine-script code line limits the num ber of people who can respond

Comment: Where do you define `df`?